# Iterative PostOrder Traversal of B-Tree

Tags: python

I implement the PostOrder traversal of B-Tree using Iterative methods by using two stacks and I can't figure it out why my program control is stuck in infinite Loop. Any suggestions guys why is program control goes into the infinite loop

```
          10
       /     \
      11     20
     /  \   /  \
    15  12 0    9
          / \
         16 18
   PostOrder : 15 12 11 16 18 0 9 20 10
```

Python Code:

**def PostOrderWithoutRecursion(root):**

```
stack_1 = stack_2 = []
temp = root

while True :

    stack_2.append(temp)

    if temp.left is not None:
        stack_1.append(temp.left)

    if temp.right is not None:
        stack_1.append(temp.right)

    if len(stack_1) == 0:
        break
    else:
        temp = stack_1.pop()

while len(stack_2) :
    print(stack_2.pop().data,end=" ")
```

Comment: `stack_1` and `stack_2` are the references to the same list. You are popping from one and pushing to the other which essentially means the pop/push followed by push/pop on the same stack/list, i.e. after first push, it's not going to be empty. Initialize them separately as `stack_1, stack_2 = [], []`

Comment: thanks, man.. sometimes small mistakes lead to the big headache